# What is "gas" in a two dimensional electron gas

Tags: condensed-matter

Why do we call a [two dimensional electron gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-dimensional_electron_gas) a "gas" even though 2-DEG is formed on the interface of semiconductor heterostructures? What is the significance of the term "gas"?

Answer (score 4):

In a gas the particles are weakly interacting with long mean free paths and no correlations in position. This exactly describes the two dimensional systems of electrons you describe. The mean free paths of the electrons in these sorts of systems can be several microns, which is remarkably close to the mean free path of air molecules at normal temperatures and pressures.

In fact the conduction electrons in a conductor are also remarkably similar to a gas. The [Drude-Sommerfeld model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_electron_model) treats the conduction electrons as a three dimensional gas.